# SQL: Joining a table with itself and allowing null in result

Tags: sql, join, null, full-outer-join

I have a table like this:

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | Type | Value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | 111   |
+----+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | 222   |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | B    | 333   |
+----+------+-------+
| 3  | A    | 444   |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | C    | 555   |
+----+------+-------+
```

`ID` is not unique but `ID` together with `Type` creates a unique key. I want it to return the values for both `Type:A` and `Type:B` with `ID:1`. This is the code I use:

```
select tA.ID, tA.Value as ValueA, tB.Value as ValueB
from Table_1 tA 
join Table_1 tB on tA.ID = tB.ID and (tA.Type = 'A' and tB.Type = 'B')
where tA.ID = 1
```

This returns the *correct* result:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueA | ValueB |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 111    | 333    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

But if it's missing a `Type:B` for `ID:1`, like so:

```
+----+------+-------+
| ID | Type | Value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | A    | 111   |
+----+------+-------+
| 2  | B    | 222   |
+----+------+-------+
| 3  | A    | 444   |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | C    | 555   |
+----+------+-------+
```

...and I run the same code as above, it returns an *empty* result.

I want it to return the following result if it's missing a `Type:B`:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueA | ValueB |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 111    | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

Or if it's missing `Type:A` but has a `Type:B`, then the result should be:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueA | ValueB |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | NULL   | 333    |
+----+--------+--------+
```

If both Type:A and Type:B are missing, then it *doesn't matter* if they return empty **or** include NULLs like this:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueA | ValueB |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | NULL   | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I tried using `full outer join`:

```
select tA.ID, tA.Value as ValueA, tB.Value as ValueB
from Table_1 tA 
full outer join Table_1 tB on tA.ID = tB.ID and (tA.Type = 'A' and tB.Type = 'B')
where tA.ID = 1
```

... but it returns a result that includes the value of `Type:C` as `ValueA`:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| ID | ValueA | ValueB |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 111    | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
| 1  | 555    | NULL   |
+----+--------+--------+
```

How can I fix my code to return a result that will include a null value for a missing `Type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pair `ID` and `Type` is unique, you can `group by id` and use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  id,
  max(case type when 'A' then value end) ValueA,
  max(case type when 'B' then value end) ValueB
from Table_1 
where id = 1 and type in ('A', 'B')
group by id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2AivZCb7tHs1hkT1ZdyL7E/0).
Results:

```
| id  | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | 111    | 333    |
```

or:

```
| id  | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   | 111    |        |
```

or:

```
| id  | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | ------ | ------ |
| 1   |        | 333    |
```

for the different cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `full join`, but filtering is tricky.  This will work:

```
select tA.ID, tA.Value as ValueA, tB.Value as ValueB
from (select tA.*
      from Table_1 tA
      where tA.ID = 1 and tA.Type = 'A'
     ) tA full join
     (select tB.*
      from Table_2 tB
      where tB.ID = 1 and tB.Type = 'B'
     ) tB
     on tA.ID = tB.ID ;
```

I *think* this also works:

```
select tA.ID, tA.Value as ValueA, tB.Value as ValueB
from Table_1 tA full join
     Table_1 tB 
     on tA.ID = tB.ID
where (tA.ID = 1 or tB.ID = 1) and
      (tA.Type = 'A' or tA.Type is null) and
      (tA.Type = 'B' or tB.Type is null);
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one worked, but the second one didn't.